# Flattening using a recursive function

Tags: python, list, function, recursion

```
def flatten(data):
  output=[]
  for item in data:
    if type(item)==list:
      flatten(item)              
      #Correct code: output += flatten 
    else:
      output.append(item)
      return output


example=[[1,2,3],[4,[5,6]],7,[8,9]]
print("before:",example)
print("after:",flatten(example))
```

I don't know why my code is wrong.
Isn't the output list called again when the recursive function is called?
Is the empty output list being called continuously in the execution of the code I wrote? (Does the output list go through the process of being initialized each time it is called?)

Comment: Please fix your formatting, see [this question for information on how to do that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: this could be done using list comprehension but I don't suppose that's of any interest?

Comment: Change `type(item)==list` line to `isinstance(item, list)`  bcoz thats the way to check data-type in python

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you use 'flatten(item)' and then **return** the output. This inconsistency makes the line 'flatten(item)' do absolutely nothing. The returned value is not saved. Also, I would suggest using the isinstance function. A possible correction would be:

```py
def flatten(data):
   output = []
   for item in data:
      if (isinstance(item, list)):
         item = flatten(item)
         output+=item #or output.extend(item)
      else:
         item.append(item) #or item+=[item]
      output.append(item)
   return output
```

**EDIT :** upon seeing your code again I (and specifcally the function name) I see you might want to change the list "data" and not return a new list "output" whose values are data's values flattened. A solution for that would be:

```py
def flatten(data):
   output = []
   for item in data:
      if (isinstance(item, list)):
         flatten(item)
         output+=item #or output.extend(item)
      else:
         item.append(item) #or item+=[item]
      output.append(item)
   data = output
```

A short explanation for why your code is wrong: *say* that the function works miraculously in the line `flatten(item)` (that is, the function manages to make the `data` flattened). The function **returns** a new copy of `item` flattened (`output`) and does not change  it (you may want to look into `pointers`). Then, `item` is unchanged and is added to a new output list, which you then return.

My first solution will work because we "embrace" returning the solution (which has its perks, `data` is unchanged). We save the returned value of `flatten(data)` and add it to output, which we then return.

My second solution will work because we "embrace" changing data. That is, switching the `pointer` in data to the new list.